# User account validation with code in an email link

Tags: php, email, user-interface, registration, email-validation

I am trying to make a little system where a user signs up to my site and they get one of those emails that has a link in which they click to activate their account.

So far I am thinking of doing it the following way:

1. User signs up and presses submit.
2. A long random string is created and put into the database against this new "inactive" account.
3. An email is sent to the address the user gave, containing a link to say "www.mysite.com/userclass/validationmethod/user@email.com/3423frqfafkop2341o43". The last bit being the validation code.
4. The user clicks the link.
5. The email and code match up to the account just created. The account is marked as validated/active.
6. The validation code that is stored in the database is deleted or marked as used??

What are your thoughts on this? Is this the best way to do it? As a little extra question, do I need to urlencode that email address?

---

I have gone with the following which seems to work well. Just have to add the database functions and it's sorted:

```
public function verifyAccount($vCode, $email) {
        $email = urldecode($email);
        if($userId = $this->model->userIdByEmail($email))
        {
            $actualCode = $this->model->getUsersVerificationCodes('code', 'userId', $userId);
            if($actualCode != $vCode)
            {
                $output = 'Invalid code or email.';
            } else {
                $output = 'Success!';
            }
        } else {
            $output = 'Invalid code or email.';
        }

        echo $output;
}
```

Comment: I would include a unique field in the url as well, such as user id, so /userid/string, this will make your query on the database lighter as you match two fields instead of searching for just one. It also takes away the issue where a more than one user could have the same activation hash/string (the chance of this happening isn't much, but it's a possibility!)

Comment: You Don't need to pass email address in URL. Send Unique Validation code which you are already saving in your DB. In verification process, do check if code is valid or not. if valid code has been found then update user verification status.

Comment: @JoãoFerreira Do you think I should keep the validation code and mark it as used? I could also put a date on it so I could set expiries perhaps?

Comment: @imperium2335 Could be useful lots of site are sending email verification which are only valid for 48h or something else. But depending on how much user you are expecting you should consider the amount of data you have to keep in you database <= signup gets slower maybe

Comment: You have a lot of possibilities, maybe you should create another field in the users table to mark the user as activated, or an activation date field, or just clear the hash/string field (null)...

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution: _“You Don't need to pass email address in URL. Send Unique Validation code which you are already saving in your DB. In verification process, do check if code is valid or not.”_ – then I will just have to flood your script with enough “random” codes to get _every_ account activated sooner or later.

Comment: @CBroe - Well It's all depends on how complex logic developer can make. Here Developer also can go for valid verification code checking or  verification code expiration after certain amount of time or resend verification code process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine to me i would also do this. But i wouldn't use the e-mail in the link. Use instead something like this:
`mysite.com/confirm_email/749c71f6a29220a3ec168df`

EDIT: I think you don't need to urlencode the email but when you do it it might be easier to handle the adress.

I think another possible option would be:

`mysite.com?email=urlencoded_email&confirm=u34h23ui4h234` depending on how you are handling url parameters.

Comment: +1 Good point. I guess I don't need the email address because it's not like someone is going to guess a big random string for someone else's account.

Comment: If you have _just_ the “big random string”, then I’ll just have to flood your script with enough of those random strings to get _any_ account activated sooner or later … so you should also transmit something identifying the account in question as well (email or id) to prevent that.

Comment: @CBroe Agreed, I'm going to go with sending the email in addition to the code rather than the users id. I think the email is much better than the id which is just a number, or do you think they are the same?

Comment: This is interesting to think about actually. If a person wanted to register a bogus email then what difference does it make if you also have the email in the link? They created that bogus email when they signed up so they'll know that and just put it in, and then they run a script to guess the string and it's the same now as if not having the email. So, no point in putting the email in really.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there is no point in putting the email address in the link. If a person wanted to figure out this after they created a fake email, then already know the fake email and just add it to the link they will be spamming your server with to guess the random number. So just have the (large) random number (as random as you can get).

However, what you should do is put an expiration field for validation. You should only make that random number valid for maybe an hour or so. If they hit that link after the hour then it's no longer valid. This helps fight hackers since if they are guessing they need time and each fake account they register they get a new random number and only 1 hour of guessing time. If you can get a very long and good random number that should do a better job of fighting against hackers.

In your email have a support link for users to request another validation code and handle this manually so you can see any patterns happening. This should happen all that often.